# Warning: mysql_num_rows() But only on webhost, not localhost

Tags: mysql

On localhost this works great. But when I upload files to server I get this error:

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /storage/content/04/13fd39104/xxxxx.com/public_html/users/list.php on line 54

My code is:

```
    //load users from database
    $users = mysql_query("SELECT id,username FROM ".$sql_table_users." WHERE id!='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($users) > 0){
        while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)){
            //ALT tag contains user ID and user name 
            print '&bull; <a href="#" alt="'.$user['id'].'|'.$user['username'].'" class="chat_user">'.$user['username'].'</a><br />';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have the same db strutture on server? Probably some column or table name are different from localhost. Check also if your db connection credentials are correct

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your database on server is not the same as your localhost.

add echo mysql_error(); after mysql_query to see details.

Comment: Sorry! Im an idiot!I did export my local database, but I changed one field locally and forgot to change on server!

Comment: Ok, try to be expert!

Answer (score 0):

I would echo the query string before performing the query to see if it really is the string you think it should be. Most likely one of the variables is not defined so the query is failing. If that doesn't help you could also output any mysql errors after the query.

And of course, the obligatory suggestion to get off of the deprecated mysql_* functions! If you don't want to do PDO, check out mysqli and how very similar it is to the mysql functions if you use the procedural functions.